# bash: no need to call popd after pushd at the end of a script?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, stack, pushd

I was going through some trouble to do some proper "pushd/popd cleanup" in my bash script. That is: if I did `pushd` a few times, I wanted to make sure to do the same number of `popd` before `exit`.

However, I noticed that the pushd/popd stack doesn't seem to be global.

Suppose I have this script called `example-pushd-twice.sh` in my homedir:

```
pushd /etc
pushd /tmp
```

And I do this from the shell from within my homedir: (resulting output in blockquotes)

`dirs`

> ~

`./example-pushd-twice.sh`

> /etc ~
>   /tmp /etc ~

I now expected to still be in `/tmp` and still having a dir stack with 3 dirs, however:

`dirs`

> ~

Is this correct behavior? Can I trust a shell script to invoke its own pushd/popd stack, so I don't have to care about cleaning up afterwards?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Directory stack is gone when the shell (interpreter of you script) exits. This is the same behavior you would get if you ran `/bin/bash` from your interactive shell. Did `pushd /tmp`. And then typed `exit`. The shell you are returning to is not affected by what happened inside that other `bash` process.

However, in a situation when you source your script (i.e. you run the commands within current `bash` process) instead of executing it (creating new shell instance) the directory stack would still linger around after last line of sourced file finished. Instead of `./example-pushd-twice.sh` run `source ./example-pushd-twice.sh` and observe the difference. For that reason, if you rely on `pushd` in your script, it would still be prudent to `popd` before it finishes.

Answer (score 2):

Not only is the `pushd` `popd` stack gone, any `cd` operations that you do in a script are also gone.

Simply put scripts run in a subshell unless you `source` them.

All `pushd`, `popd`, `cd`, `function`, `alias`, `set` or `export` operations will not affect the environment once the script has completed.

As  Ondrej says. you should only worry about cleanup if your script will be run with `source`